# IllegalArgumentException: Local name may not be null or empty

Tags: weblogic, illegalargumentexception

I have a problem with a webservices that I need to deploy on my server.

When I deploy it on my local environment on Tomcat and xercesImpl.jar I have no problem.

**Tomcat 7, java 6, xercesImpl 2.9.1**

The issue come up when I deploy the war on Weblogic.
I have tried to deploy without the xercesImpl.jar as I know that Weblogic has own implementation and I recive this issue:

**Weblogic 12g Java 6**

```
[2015-05-12 13:30:35,940] ERROR org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine {[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' } -
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(WSDoAllReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllHandler.invoke(WSDoAllHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:317)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:264)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:163)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3366)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ciccio.ta.application.ServiceAppHelper.getSecurityService(ServiceAppHelper.java:171)
        at com.ciccio.ta.application.Application.getSecurityService(Application.java:810)
        at com.ciccio.ta.application.Application.getSecurityService(Application.java:794)
        at com.ciccio.ta.kernel.TaContext.preProcessRequest(TaContext.java:1510)
        at com.ciccio.ta.services2.security.PasswordCallBackHandlerServer.handle(PasswordCallBackHandlerServer.java:79)
        at org.apache.ws.security.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleUsernameToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:145)
        at org.apache.ws.security.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:53)
        at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:311)
        at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:228)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(WSDoAllReceiver.java:211)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(WSDoAllReceiver.java:86)
        ... 25 more
[2015-05-12 13:30:36,303] ERROR org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine {[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' } -
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(WSDoAllReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllHandler.invoke(WSDoAllHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:317)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:264)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:163)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3366)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ciccio.ta.application.ServiceAppHelper.getSecurityService(ServiceAppHelper.java:171)
        at com.ciccio.ta.application.Application.getSecurityService(Application.java:810)
        at com.ciccio.ta.application.Application.getSecurityService(Application.java:794)
        at com.ciccio.ta.kernel.TaContext.preProcessRequest(TaContext.java:1510)
        at com.ciccio.ta.services2.security.PasswordCallBackHandlerServer.handle(PasswordCallBackHandlerServer.java:79)
        at org.apache.ws.security.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleUsernameToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:145)
        at org.apache.ws.security.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:53)
        at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:311)
        at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:228)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(WSDoAllReceiver.java:211)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(WSDoAllReceiver.java:86)
        ... 25 more
[2015-05-12 13:35:31,630] INFO  startup.com.ciccio.ta.jmx.SystemInfoLogger {TASystemThread } - VMID= 4843173, 12/05/2015 13:35:31 IST, MaxMemory=932352, MaxMemoryUsedPercent=27, MemoryTotal=613376, MemoryUsed=258208, NumberBOEs=0,
```

If I deploy the war file with xercesImpl.jar and changing the weblogic.xml as follow:

```
 <container-descriptor>
        <servlet-reload-check-secs>-1</servlet-reload-check-secs>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>
```

I receive a different error:

```
[2015-05-12 13:47:14,895] ERROR com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut {[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ff-sm-03, null, "null", PE:01000:0000012877, null, null, TaContext-2, 3, 0} - A marshalling exception occured for the type com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.GetReportsResponse:
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Local name may not be null or empty]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:316)
        at com.ciccio.ta.services2.validation.TaValidationHandler.validateMarshallerAgainstSchema(TaValidationHandler.java:103)
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.toOM(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:1064)
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.toEnvelope(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:1098)
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:157)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3366)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Local name may not be null or empty
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMAttributeImpl.<init>(OMAttributeImpl.java:56)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addAttribute(OMElementImpl.java:612)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.SAXOMBuilder.startElement(SAXOMBuilder.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ContentHandlerRecord.openAndCloseStartElement(ContentHandlerRecord.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ContentHandlerRecord.openStartElement(ContentHandlerRecord.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ValidatingMarshalRecord.openStartElement(ValidatingMarshalRecord.java:170)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.startElement(XPathNode.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:1240)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:833)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:788)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:314)
        ... 28 more
[2015-05-12 13:47:14,899] ERROR remote.com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut {[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ff-sm-03, null, "null", PE:01000:0000012877, null, null, TaContext-2, 3, 0} - A marshalling exception occured for the type com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.GetReportsResponse:
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Local name may not be null or empty]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:316)
        at com.ciccio.ta.services2.validation.TaValidationHandler.validateMarshallerAgainstSchema(TaValidationHandler.java:103)
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.toOM(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:1064)
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.toEnvelope(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:1098)
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:157)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3366)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Local name may not be null or empty
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMAttributeImpl.<init>(OMAttributeImpl.java:56)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addAttribute(OMElementImpl.java:612)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.SAXOMBuilder.startElement(SAXOMBuilder.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ContentHandlerRecord.openAndCloseStartElement(ContentHandlerRecord.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ContentHandlerRecord.openStartElement(ContentHandlerRecord.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ValidatingMarshalRecord.openStartElement(ValidatingMarshalRecord.java:170)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.startElement(XPathNode.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:1240)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:833)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:788)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:314)
        ... 28 more
[2015-05-12 13:47:14,930] ERROR org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine {[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ff-sm-03, null, "null", PE:01000:0000012877, null, null, TaContext-2, 3, 0} - ValidationException
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: ValidationException
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.createAxisFault(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:1377)
        at com.ciccio.reports.operationtypes.ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(ReportingServicesMessageReceiverInOut.java:187)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3366)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

Any help???

Thanks

Comment: Fixed, after same investigation with my colleague L.D. he fix my problem, was a version JAXB Providers that Weblogic has build inside. I have just override it following this documentation (Using the Glassfish RI JAXB Data Binding and JAXB Providers) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/data_types.htm#WSGET345

Comment: Please add the solution you came up with as an answer so people know this question has been resolved.

Comment: As I have already commented the solution is in the article that I have linked... Open the link and go to the paragraph "Using the Glassfish RI JAXB Data Binding and JAXB Providers" is really detailed well much better that I could do.

Comment: Configuring Global Server-Level Data Binding and JAXB Providers

The following jar file is provided in the WebLogic Server distribution to simplify the task of overriding the default data binding configuration:

modules/databinding.override_1.0.0.0.jar

This jar file is not included in the classpath by default. To restore the Glassfish RI data binding and JAXB provider settings, edit the WebLogic Server start script to prepend this jar file to the classpath.